# Compute an improper integral.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Suppose $A = [0,\infty) \times [0, \infty) $. Let $f(x,y) = (x+y)e^{-x-y} $. How can I find $ \int_A f $? I know since $f$ is continuous on $A$, then $\int _A f $ exists, Do I need to evaluate

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} (x+y)e^{-x-y}\ dx\ dy\ ??$$

Comment: Yes, that will do it. There are no issues, since the integrand is $\ge 0$.

Comment: I found that this integral is $0$. is it correct?

Comment: I suggest you to evaluate the integral since it's easy to be obtained by using Gamma function definition.

Comment: @MathcanbeFun: Impossible, the integrand is positive. If you know something about the exponential distribution, you can see at a glance that the answer is $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_M$ be the set $[0,M]\times [0, M]$ and $I_M=\int_{A_M}{f}$. From Fubini's Theorem
\begin{align}
I_M&=\int_{y=0}^{y=M}\left[\int_{x=0}^{x=M}(x+y)e^{-(x+y)}dx\right]dy \\
   &=\int_{y=0}^{y=M}\left[-(x+y+1)e^{-(x+y)}\right]_{x=0}^{x=M}dy \\
   &=\int_{y=0}^{y=M}\left[(y+1)e^{-y}-(M+y+1)e^{-(M+y)}\right]dy \\
   &=\left[-(y+2)e^{-y}+(M+y+2)e^{-(M+y)}\right]_{y=0}^{y=M} \\
   &=-(M+2)e^{-M}+2+2(M+1)e^{-2M}-(M+2)e^{-M} \\
   &=2-2(M+2)e^{-M}+2(M+1)e^{-2M}
\end{align}
Now, 
\begin{align}
\int_A{f}&=\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty}{I_M} \\
         &=\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty}{\left[2-2(M+2)e^{-M}+2(M+1)e^{-2M}\right]} \\
         &=2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**HINT :**

Rewrite:
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} (x+y)e^{-x-y} dx dy =\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y} \int_{0}^{\infty} (x+y)e^{-x} dx dy\tag1
$$
Note that
$$
\int_0^\infty z^n e^{-z}\ dz=(n+1)!\tag2
$$
Use $(2)$ to evaluate $(1)$.